# Google+ OAuth2 Flow in Android: Ensure offline access using the temporary auth code

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-oauth, client-side, android-permissions

### [- Summary -]

**Problem**: I am trying to implement a [Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) with [server-side API access](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) for an Android app. I am encountering a problem where *sometimes* `offline` access is not granted by the temporary access code, resulting in an `invalid_grant` error on the backend.

**Question**: How can I make sure, on the client side, that the access code that is forwarded to the server includes an `offline` access permission?

### [ Elaboration ]

During a Google+ OAuth flow in Android, [`GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns a temporary auth code that is later exchanged for an access token to the requested [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes).

It is mentioned (at the time of writing of this post) in [Google's own code example](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) that:

> Requesting an authorization code will always throw
>   UserRecoverableAuthException on the first call to
>   GoogleAuthUtil.getToken because the user must consent to offline
>   access to their data.  After consent is granted control is returned to
>   your activity in onActivityResult and the second call to
>   GoogleAuthUtil.getToken will succeed.

Over the course of development, I encountered scenarios where the "offline access" dialog pops (and fails to return a code), where it doesn't pop (and returns a broken code), where it pops and even though the user consents the code is still wrong... and also successful attempts. The app behavior seems to alternate between these scenarios even when introducing seemingly auth-unrelated modifications. *{Edit1: Upon further reading, I think that the seemingly arbitrary behavior of the flow stems from old codes being stored inside the AccountManager, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852256/how-do-you-force-accountmanager-to-show-the-access-request-screen-after-a-user/)}*

I have also encountered the familiar behavior of peculiar {*read: poorly synchronized?*} app-flow when debugging (as opposed to *running*) asynchronous code (because debugging allows tasks running on the UI thread to conclude before\after tasks in [the asynchronous thread (see section on "Order of execution")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ).

So far I've (implicitly) only treated the case where the user is "connected" to the app (i.e. authorized the app in the past without revoking its access, as can be found in the [Manage apps page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps)), however, this problem is exacerbated for new users (since they are presented with two different permission dialogs in the first place).

I am really puzzled on how this entire process should be coded properly {this is why I didn't bother including my own code}, and whether it is truly *this complicated* or it's just me. For me, it is most important to understand why this happens and what can be done to enforce a well-architected and uniform execution flow while avoiding [blindly copying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (which got me into this mess in the first place :P).

Currently my best guess is to somehow get the "latest granted permission of the oauth dialog" and raise flag accordingly.

Additional Information:

- The activity during which log-in takes place has `android:launchMode="singleTop"` defined in the manifest {this was done to handle deeplinks properly}.
- In the latest iteration, my `getToken` calls originate from within [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) objects executed using [`executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29). This is the only kind of [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) I currently have.

#### Theories as to why this happens:

1. AsyncTask concurrency - the various checks for the validity of the auth code attempt to access static variables that may be changed by a task running on a different thread (UI vs. async.) {if it *is* the case - it counter-intuitively doesn't result in exceptions}
2. Faulty logic - assuming that a valid code appears on the 2nd attempt (or any other  number thereof) is faulty logic for checking code validity.

#### Attempts\ideas to solve this:

1. Having a flag in place that tracks whether it's the 1st or 2nd time the auth code was received. {*Attempt didn't work, probably due to concurrency - see above.*}
2. Obtaining "currently granted permissions" (from the OS, Google utils, [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthTokenByFeatures%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) or etc.), and checking that offline access is present there.
3. Obtaining the latest permission granted from the Intent contained in [UserRecoverableAuthException](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException.html) (during the host activity's [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), in the task's [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) or elsewhere). {*Not tested yet*}

### Related questions (random order):

[Google+ Sign-in for Android - Google Permissions Activity Result Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184548/google-sign-in-for-android-google-permissions-activity-result-codes)

[Android Google+ integration - repeated UserRecoverableAuthException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713435/android-google-integration-repeated-userrecoverableauthexception/)

[Google Plus Single Sign On Server Flow - Google_AuthException Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950655/google-plus-single-sign-on-server-flow-google-authexception-error-fetching-oau)